# Connect to a webserver running in Windows 7 using IP from a brower

Tags: windows-7, webserver

I'm not sure if this is the proper place to ask this question.

Here is my issue

I'm using windows 7 and i have installed Zope Server.(Zope is python web framework which has a built-in server). I can connect to this server from my browser by typing,

```
localhost:8080
```

But if i try to connect this server from another machine using my IP or even from my own system it doesn't work.
ie

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080
```

Comment: what are the contents of your ipconfig /all

Comment: You can try changing `address 127.0.0.1:80` in your `zope.conf` to `0.0.0.0:80` (port number depends on your `port-base`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with your firewall. In windows, please open port 8080.

1. Open Control Panel from the Start menu.
2. Select Windows Firewall.
3. Note: If Windows Firewall is not available, change View by to Large
   icons at the top right of the Control Panel window.
4. Select Advanced settings in the left column of the Windows Firewall
   window.
5. Select Inbound Rules in the left column of the Windows Firewall with
   Advanced Security window.
6. Note: You can prevent outbound traffic by selecting Outbound Rules.
7. Select New Rule in the right column.
8. Select Port in the New Inbound Rule Wizard and then click Next.
9. Select which protocol this rule will apply to (TCP or UDP), select
   Specific local ports, type a port number (8080) (or port numbers
   (8080,8081)).
10. Select Allow the connection and then click Next.
11. Select when this rule applies (check all of them for the port to
    always stay open) and then click Next.
12. Give this rule a name and then click Finish to add the new rule.
13. The port is now open and ready to be used.

Although typically, the local port to use is port 80.

Comment: Well spotted. I read it as 80 as that's what I always use. Thanks, edited my answer.